# Proof of Invertible Relation Between Two Functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f: \Bbb N \times \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb N$ s.t.

$f(m,n) = [1+2+\cdot\cdot\cdot+n] +[(n+2)+(n+3)+\cdot\cdot\cdot+(n+m+1)]$

$=[1+2+3+\cdot\cdot\cdot+(m+n)]+m$
$=1/2[(m+n)^2+3m+n]$

Let $g: \Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb N \times \Bbb N$

$g(k)=(k-1/2l(l+1),l-[k-1/2l(l+1)])$ where $1/2(l)(l+1)\le k \lt (l+1)(l+2)$
for $k,l \in \Bbb N$

How could one show that f,g are invertible function to each other?

Comment: Consider the composition $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$. Show that they are identity functions on their respective domains.

Comment: @AnuragA ah-ha! Composition was the key. thx

Comment: @AnuragA could you help me to verify the case of $g\comp f$ I am suffering from the trouble of finding the appropriate $l$ in this case